# Correlated subquery in having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I am working with a default oracle `scott` database with additional table `PROJECT`, where there are there are 5 columns: projno, projname, budget, start_date, end_date.

I want to select month with the highest number of projects in a specific year.
In instruction to my exercise it is said that it must be done with correlated subquery.

I know how to do it with `uncorrelated subquery`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month FROM end_date) as "Month", COUNT(*) as "No of projects"
FROM proj
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM end_date) = 2016
GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM end_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))
               FROM proj
               WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM end_date) = 2016
               GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM end_date))
```

Here is my try with `correlated subquery` -  it doesn't work:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(month FROM end_date)), COUNT(*) as "liczba"
FROM proj p
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM end_date) = 2016
GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM end_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) =  MAX (SELECT(COUNT(EXTRACT(month FROM proj.end_date)))
                FROM proj
                WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM proj.end_date) = EXTRACT(month FROM p.end_date) 
AND EXTRACT(year FROM proj.end_date) = 2016)
```

Comment: Window functions are much better approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Are you getting an error message or are you not getting the correct data?

Comment: @msturek ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"